# Mapping specific interface implementation to interface destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I have several mappings in my AutoMapper profile for the same source and destination types. The destination type is an interface which has several concrete implementations.
Depending on the scenario, I would map to the appropriate concrete implementation of IEmployeeDto.

```cs
// Model
public class Department
{
  public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentDto
{
  public List<IEmployeeDto> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDto1 : IEmployeeDto 
{
  ...
}

public class EmployeeDto2 : IEmployeeDto
{
  ...
}

// Mappings
profile.CreateMap<Employee, IEmployeeDto>()
  .As<EmployeeDto1>();

profile.CreateMap<Employee, IEmployeeDto>()
  .As<EmployeeDto2>();
```

I'm using Entity Framework as well.
In runtime, I'm using projections to map:

```cs
var department = context.Departments
  .ProjectTo<DeparmentDto>(config)
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Name == departmentName);

//In this specific use case, I'm expecting EmployeeDto2 instead of EmployeeDto1
var employees = department.Employees;
```

Is there any way to hint which concrete implementation of the destination type should be mapped to?

Comment: A map is identified by the source and destination types, so you actually overwrite the one map. You'll have to rethink things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "hint" which concrete implementation it should use by specifying an AutoMapper mapping which has been configured to use the specific type. When you write

```
profile.CreateMap<Employee, IEmployeeDto>().As<EmployeeDto1>();
```

it will use the specific `EmployeeDto1` class when a `Employee` object should be mapped to a `IEmployeeDto` instance. If you want a different mapping simply change the configured mapping in the AutoMapper configuration or use a different AutoMapper configuration itself (which has the different mapping configured). You can have multiple instances of `MapperConfiguration` objects, each with it's own configuration. The `ProjectTo()` method requires a configuration to use, so you can swap the configuration depending on your requirements.

Comment: I created separate profiles now for the different scenarios. 
Prior to the data retrieval, I build up a new MapperConfiguration object that contains the correct profile.